# Npgsql: What does `AddEntityFrameworkNpgsqlTrigrams` do?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-core, npgsql

Since Ngpsql docs doesn't have a [comperhensive page](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/full-text-search.html?tabs=pg12) for *fuzzy* string matching, I went with what [test cases](https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/pull/1085/commits/46fc51f72f8f3376abc83bb924cd706ef1421a07) are using, and got the following error:

```
Exception has occurred: CLR/System.AggregateException
An unhandled exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in API.dll: 'Some services are not able to be constructed'
    Inner exceptions found, see $exception in variables window for more details.
    Innermost exception      System.InvalidOperationException : Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.IRelationalTypeMappingSource' while attempting to activate 'Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.           PostgreSQL.Query.ExpressionTranslators.Internal.NpgsqlTrigramsMethodCallTranslatorPlugin'.
    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean            throwIfCallSiteNotFound)
    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite(ResultCache lifetime, Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(ServiceDescriptor descriptor, Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, Int32 slot)
    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.GetCallSite(ServiceDescriptor serviceDescriptor, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor descriptor)
```

Normally I'd ask what's happening, but I've noticed that if I don't use [AddEntityFrameworkNpgsqlTrigrams](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/api/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.NpgsqlTrigramsServiceCollectionExtensions.html#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_NpgsqlTrigramsServiceCollectionExtensions_AddEntityFrameworkNpgsqlTrigrams_IServiceCollection_), I'm able to compile and my call to a trigram function (TrigramsSimilarity to be exact) results in my expression being translated successfully. So my question is: What is AddEntityFrameworkNpgsqlTrigrams for? Can I leave it out? 
I should note that I'm using Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Trigrams version 3.1.4. We haven't migrated to .NET 5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to use the Trigram plugin is to take a reference on the [Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Trigrams](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Trigrams/) nuget package, and call [UseTrigrams](http://www.npgsql.org/efcore/api/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.NpgsqlTrigramsDbContextOptionsBuilderExtensions.html#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_NpgsqlTrigramsDbContextOptionsBuilderExtensions_UseTrigrams_) in your `OnModelConfiguring`:

```cs
options.UseNpgsql(@"<connection string>", o => o.UseTrigrams())
```

[This is documented here](http://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/translations.html#trigram-functions). Applications rarely need to call AddEntityFrameworkNpgsqlTrigrams directly.

Comment: Thanks for implying I don't need it, but the question remains what AddEntityFrameworkNpgsqlTrigrams is for. Be advised that it is the 3rd search result for "npgsql trigrams", whereas the Translations page you've linked to is nowhere to be found

Comment: The docs on trigram support have just been added a few days ago, hopefully they will be indexed soon. AddEntityFrameworkNpgsqlTrigrams adds the necessary service(s) to the EF internal dependency injection container - it's one of the things that happen when you call UseTrigrams. It's very rare for a user application to need to call it directly.